# Print nginx server settings to page

Tags: nginx, echo

I need to output the proxy_pass address when a user navigate to a specific location. Do I need to install http://openresty.org/ just to do this:

```
set $gateway_proxy http://myproxy.com;

location /gateway {
    default_type text/html;
    echo $gateway_proxy;
}
```

Comment: No, you don't. You can return arbitrary text along with the response code using [return](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) directive. Just replace your `echo` with `return 200 $gateway_proxy;`.

Comment: Awesome! I thought that was a bit much to install for this.